# How does importing this submodule overwrite a value in the parent __init__.py module?

Tags: python

I have a [package with three files](https://github.com/posita/testimport/tree/master/testimport):

```
testimport
├── __init__.py
├── logging.py
└── util.py
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
from __future__ import ( absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals )
import logging # imports standard library module (because absolute_import is activated)
_logging_file = logging.__file__
from .util import testlog
if _logging_file != logging.__file__:
    # at this point, `logging` no longer points to the standard
    # library module, but the local logging module instead(!)
    raise AssertionError('`logging` overwritten; {!r} is not equal to {!r}'.format(_logging_file, logging.__file__))
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

`logging.py` contains:

```
import sys
__all__ = ()
SILENT = -(sys.maxsize) - 1
```

`util.py` contains:

```
from __future__ import ( absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals )
import logging # imports standard library module (because absolute_import is activated)
from .logging import SILENT # this is (perversely) where the importing module's `logging` gets overridden
__all__ = ( 'testlog' )
_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def testlog(log_lvl=SILENT):
    _LOGGER.log(log_lvl, 'Hello!')
```

The `AssertionError` is raised when `import`ing `testimport`:

```
% python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 24 2015, 10:13:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import testimport
<function testlog at 0x10e86e1b8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "testimport/__init__.py", line ..., in <module>
    raise AssertionError('`logging` overwritten; {!r} is not equal to {!r}'.format(_logging_file, logging.__file__))
AssertionError: `logging` overwritten; '/.../lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc' is not equal to 'testimport/logging.pyc'
```

Why on earth is that happening?

Test repo is [here](https://github.com/posita/testimport). Travis builds are [here](https://travis-ci.org/posita/testimport).

Update, when stepping through this with [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), it appears that the offending instruction is `from .logging import SILENT` in `util.py`, but I have no idea why. This is an abbreviated session from the repo version:

```
% echo 'import testimport' >|testme.py
% python -m pdb testme.py
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /.../testimport/testimport/__init__.py(1)<module>()
-> from __future__ import (
(Pdb) b 12
Breakpoint 1 at /.../testimport/testimport/__init__.py:12
(Pdb) c
> /.../testimport/testimport/__init__.py(12)<module>()
-> from testimport.util import testlog
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /.../testimport/testimport/util.py(1)<module>()
-> from __future__ import (
(Pdb) b 5
Breakpoint 2 at /.../testimport/testimport/util.py:5
(Pdb) c
> /.../testimport/testimport/util.py(5)<module>()
-> from .logging import SILENT
(Pdb) u
> /.../testimport/testimport/__init__.py(12)<module>()
-> from testimport.util import testlog
(Pdb) p logging
<module 'logging' from '/.../lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>
(Pdb) d
> /.../testimport/testimport/util.py(5)<module>()
-> from .logging import SILENT
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /.../testimport/testimport/logging.py(1)<module>()
-> from __future__ import (
(Pdb) b 6
Breakpoint 3 at /.../testimport/testimport/logging.py:6
(Pdb) c
> /.../testimport/testimport/logging.py(6)<module>()
-> SILENT = -(sys.maxsize) - 1
(Pdb) u
> /.../testimport/testimport/util.py(5)<module>()
-> from .logging import SILENT
(Pdb) u
> /.../testimport/testimport/__init__.py(12)<module>()
-> from testimport.util import testlog
(Pdb) p logging
<module 'logging' from '/.../lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>
(Pdb) s
> /.../testimport/testimport/util.py(7)<module>()
-> 'testlog',
(Pdb) u
> /.../testimport/testimport/__init__.py(12)<module>()
-> from testimport.util import testlog
(Pdb) p logging
<module 'testimport.logging' from 'testimport/logging.pyc'>
```

Comment: Can you print _logging_file and logging.__file__ ?
Also, if you comment out from .util import testlog does _logging_file != logging.__file__ == True ? 
I'm just guessing that util.py is invoking some funtion in logging (not testimport.logging) that is making a new __file__ variable. So the old reference you got is no longer valid.

Comment: @CalebMauer, the values for `_logging_file ` and `logging.__file__` are printed in the last line of the interactive session in the OP. If I comment out `from .util import testlog`, then the `AssertionError` is not raised. However, if I do `from testlog.util import testlog`, I also get the `AssertionError` (so I'm pretty sure it isn't an artifact of the dot notation).

Comment: Regarding the comment, "I'm just guessing that util.py is invoking some funtion in logging (not testimport.logging) that is making a new **file** variable," I'm not sure I understand what that means. Can you elaborate? I guess my question boils down to: How can `from .util import testlog` affect the module-scoped variables in the *importing* module without modifying them explicitly (you can see above that `util.py` does nothing explicit with its parent).

Comment: I think that when util does from .logging import SILENT it is overwriting the double underscore file variable. I'm not sure why it would do that yet considering your absolute_import, so I'm not posting an answer yet. Just a guess.

Comment: @CalebMauer, it's probably not overwriting the `__file__` attribute to `logging` in the parent module. It looks like it's replacing the entire module. Just before the `raise` statement in the OP, `dir(logging)` shows the local `logging` module's members, and none of the standard library `logging` ones: `['SILENT', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'absolute_import', 'division', 'print_function', 'sys', 'unicode_literals']`.

Comment: Yeah, you're write, probably overwriting the module. But is that because of the from .logging import SILENT line? What if you do testimport.logging in the util file?

Comment: @CalebMauer, in `util.py`, if instead I do, `from testimport.logging import SILENT`, or even, `import testimport.logging ; SILENT = testimport.logging.SILENT`, I still get the same behavior.

Comment: Well, I have no idea. Rename your module? It's possibly a bug in 2.7 since it isn't technically a full release. Is it because you're running in the interpreter instead of command line? Also, do you need to import absolute_import in your logging module? Or at the interpreter?

Comment: @CalebMauer, as you can see from the Travis builds, it happens in all versions tested (including 3.3, 3.4, and PyPy). Also, running `from __future__ import absolute_import ; import testimport` from a file (e.g., `testme.py`) exhibits the same problem as the interpreter (again, as you can see from the Travis builds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I understand the above to be the correct behavior. I am embarrassed to say that I did not see this before. It makes total sense once one understands what's happening. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules):

> #### Submodules
>
> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs, the `import` or `import-from` statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object.
>
> ...
>
> Given Python’s familiar name binding rules this might seem surprising, but it’s actually a fundamental feature of the import system.

This explanation seems to have been absent before Python 3.4, but affects all versions of Python. See [Python issue #24029](https://bugs.python.org/issue24029).

In the example above, `testimport.logging` necessarily refers to the local module. Importing it (from anywhere) installs it in `testimport` (as should be expected). It should come as no surprise that this necessarily replaces any existing `logging` member of `testimport`.